# What is the video tape in the Resident Evil 7 demo intro referring to?

Tags: video-games, resident-evil

In the Resident Evil demo 7 intro, it starts with a video tape and it says:

> "Kitchen"
>
> Found within same house as seen in footage
>
> S-VHS

I didn't understand what this means. ***What is found in the same house? The kitchen? The tape? The Kitchen is in the same house as the footage?***

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It seems pretty clear that the VHS video tape (e.g. the one with the found-footage) was **found in the same house as depicted in the tape.** A title card was subsequently added (we assume by whomever found the footage) to identify to potential viewers what they're looking at.

If it had been found elsewhere, the caption would presumably read something like

> "Kitchen"
>
> Found in a box purchased at auction.

Comment: They recorded in a VHS that  was founded already in the house?

Comment: But who is filming this ?when the tape start the camera is filming to pessons . who is holding the camera?

Comment: If it was you(playable caracter) who found the tape then it was another person who added the title card ?Or it you?

Comment: But who is filming ?It apears like your eyes and a camera at the same time..

Comment: the camera on the video where does it come from ?It's also the caracter eyes but it's not him who is filming..

Comment: You'll have to wait until you play the game :-)

Comment: Maybe  the camera recorder is atached to his eyes somehow..?